# Why doens't a negative selector work in jQuery UI Sortable's 'cancel' property?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want a row in a jQuery UI Sortable to be sortable only if it has a `cansort` class.  I have it set to `cancel: ':not(.cansort)'` but it refuses to let me sort anything at all, including the rows that have the `cansort` class.

I know I can add a disabled class explicitly, but I use the `cansort` class for other purposes, so that means each time I made something sortable I would have to remove the disabled class and add the `cansort` class.  I don't want to have to add and remove a class each time I toggle something to be sortable.

I don't want to restrict what's sortable in the `items` property because every element can be sortable and I only dynamically toggle it on and off using the `cansort` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the way that the `cancel` option is processed by the `ui.mouse` widget (a widget used by several jQueryUI widgets to handle mouse events). Check out [this line of code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js#L64):

```
elIsCancel = (typeof this.options.cancel == "string" 
    && event.target.nodeName ? 
        $(event.target).closest(this.options.cancel).length : false);
```

What this means is that your selector gets run with the `closest` on the element that was `mousedown`ed on. So lets take an `li.cansort` sortable item. That will generate a jQuery selector that looks something like this:

```
$("li.cansort").closest(":not(.cansort)").length;
```

This will *always* return a length of `1`, because the parent `ul` for all the sortable `li`s does not have the `.cansort` class. This means with that kind of selector, the sorting will *always* be canceled.

Luckily, this is easy to get around if you just include the tag name in your `cancel` selector:

```
cancel: "li:not(.cansort)"
```

**Here's an example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7hSnc/ (try removing the `li` from the `cancel` selector)

Comment: Thank you... that explains the behavior so I am going to award you the points.  My problem is that I am using sortable div elements, and they are nested inside of other divs.  So the closest function will always go up the chain of nested divs until it finds one lacking the cansort class.  Using a fork of your example where I nest the list inside of another list, it doesn't allow any to be sorted: http://jsfiddle.net/ymvZm/  This seems like a bug to me that could be fixed by bounding the closest function call to elements inside of the sortable container.

Comment: @RenderIn: No problem. You can simulate what you mentioned by adding a requirement in your selector that the `li` be a child of the sortable container: http://jsfiddle.net/UKf7F/